# Can we self host airconsole?

Tags: airconsole

The site currently doesn't make it entirely clear, though the documentation is super clean and the api looks great, if we as developers can self host the airconsole framework for our own games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AirConsole is providing the API/Service but not the possibility to host the framework by yourself.

Of course you can directly link to your game with:
http://www.airconsole.com/#http://url-to-your-game/

Comment: Cool, thanks @Zeus. Looks like an awesome tool. Do we retain all rights to our games that are uploaded?

Comment: Exactly, you keep all the rights to your games :) I will soon rework the documentation and add a bunch of more clarity to it.

Comment: Cool. Goodluck with the project it seems very exciting!